# regarding the array value of imread and rgb2gray

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image

For a given image, if I read it using imread, will the values in the three channels be in the range of [0,255]? If I transfer this image using rgb2gray, will the value be in the range of [0,1]?

based on the [skimage doc](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.rgb2gray), the calculation of rgb2gray is

```
Y = 0.2125 R + 0.7154 G + 0.0721 B
```

It seems to me that it cannot guarantee the result of rgb2gray will always belong to [0,1]. This is a bit confused.

Comment: maybe i'm missing something but grayscale is [0, 255] as well, isn't it? where 0 is black and 255 is pure white?

in which case the conversion will belong to [0, 255], because 0.2125 + .7154 + .0721 = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Images in scikit-image are converted to the range [0, 1] when they are converted to floating point (ie non-integer) types. So the pipeline in rgb2gray is to first divide by 255, then multiply by that formula. For more information, see this page:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html